# Кэширование в AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, кэширование

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с такой проблемой с кэшированием. Сначала я проверяю есть ли данные в кэше, если да, то достаю их оттуда и заношу в scope контроллера, если нет, то гружу их с сервера. Так вот, если данные уже занесены в кэш и я где-то изменю данные через `ng-model` в `$scope.players`, то они также обновятся и в кэше. Почему так происходит? Ведь нигде явно не прописано `mycache.put("players", newVals)`

```
var mycache = $cacheFactory.get("myCache");
$scope.players = mycache.get("players");

if (!$scope.players) {
    $http.get("test.php").success(function(response) {
        mycache.put("players", response);
        $scope.players = response;
    });
}
```

И еще вопрос. Можно ли как-нибудь получить доступ к данным в `mycache` через `mycahe.get()`, которые кэшируются неявно, вот таким способом:

```
var mycache = $cacheFactory.get("myCache");

$http.get("test.php", { cache: mycache }).success(function(response) {
    $scope.players = response;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для объяснения, посмотрите на этот **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gwz9gf4y/1/)**

В кэше мы сохраним объект `response`, тот же самый объект, на который `$scope.players` ссылается. Поэтому, когда обновляем `$scope.players`, обновляем одновременно то, что в кэше. Функция `put` из `$cacheFactory` выглядит вот так:

```
put: function(key, value) {
      [...]

      if (!(key in data)) size++;
      data[key] = value;  // <-- Нету копия объекта

      [...]

      return value;
}
```

Кстати говоря, функция `put` возвращает `value`, поэтому можете заменять:

```
mycache.put("players", response);
$scope.players = response;
```

со следующим:

```
$scope.players = mycache.put("players", response);
```

---

> Можно ли как-нибудь получить доступ к данным в `mycache`

Если вы хотите узнать всё, что в кэше, есть возможность использовать функцию `info()`, которая возвращает что-то в этом роде:

```
{"id": "myCache", "size": 1}
```